# Testing framework for Angular within a Rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, unit-testing

I come across Karma and Jasmine when I search for testing framework for Angular.js.

What is the best one for a medium Rails + Angular project? I am a beginner with Angular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that you seem to want to do this in RoR, I would recommend using [Teaspoon](https://github.com/modeset/teaspoon).

> Teaspoon is a Javascript test runner built for Rails. It can run tests in the browser and headless using PhantomJS, Selenium WebDriver, or Capybara Webkit.
>   ...
>   Teaspoon takes advantage of the Rails asset pipeline, and ships with support for Jasmine, Mocha, and QUnit.

The gems you'll most likely need are

```
gem 'teaspoon-jasmine'
gem 'phantomjs'
```

Following the [angular-rails.com](http://angular-rails.com) tutorial should help you get started.

Answer (score 1):

for unit testing the application, you can use the jasmine gem. You should point it to the HEAD.

```
gem "jasmine", github: "pivotal/jasmine-gem"
```

then run bundle install and rails g jasmine:install

For end-to-end tests, you can use the usual RSpec-rails and capybara. Remember when using this, to add js:true in the beginning of the scenario e.g.

```
    require "rails_helper"

RSpec.feature "new users can sign up", js: true do 
  scenario "successfully" do
 #your code here
  end
end
```

A good explanation on the unit testing using jasmine can be found here:
https://content.pivotal.io/blog/unit-testing-angularjs-in-a-rails-app-using-the-jasmine-gem